Discrepancy in Record Count Between Django ORM and Raw SQL Query
I'm encountering an issue where the count of records returned by a Django ORM query does not match the count returned by a raw SQL query. Here is the relevant part of my Django view:
start_date = datetime(2024, 10, 19, 0, 0, 0)
end_date = datetime(2024, 10, 19, 23, 59, 59)
dbug = Reservations.objects.all().filter(updated_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
print(dbug.count())

Above returns 6529
The Django settings.py contains:
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_TZ = False

I have tried SQL query same bellow:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "consultant_reservations"
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN '2024-10-19 00:00:00' AND '2024-10-19 23:59:59';
 count 
-------
  6540
(1 row)


Here is discrepancy within SQL query result (which is 6540) I have tried in psql terminal and Django ORM result (which is 6529)

Please let me presenting an example:
Trying SQL query same as:
SELECT * FROM "consultant_reservations"
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN '2024-10-19 00:00:00' AND '2024-10-19 23:59:59' LIMIT 4;

Result:
  id   |   idd   | voip_number | client_id | client_mobile | reserve_duration |  status  |   reserve_timestamp    |       created_at       |       updated_at       | consultant_id_id | mobile_id | created_by | updated_by 
-------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------------+------------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------+------------+------------
 76407 | 2011050 |        2217 |   1101151 | 09355648120   |             3600 | reserved | 2024-10-19 19:30:00+00 | 2024-10-14 08:40:03+00 | 2024-10-19 20:28:01+00 |             5052 |   2395781 |       3445 |          0
  1408 | 1958653 |        1119 |    754939 | 09142477905   |             3600 | reserved | 2024-10-19 05:30:00+00 | 2024-09-28 06:17:04+00 | 2024-10-19 06:28:01+00 |             3791 |    974986 |         87 |          0
  1514 | 1958759 |        2571 |    947805 | 09334143576   |             3600 | reserved | 2024-10-19 09:30:00+00 | 2024-09-28 06:34:05+00 | 2024-10-19 10:28:01+00 |             5374 |   1711586 |       3802 |          0
 60371 | 1997347 |        2589 |   1070143 | 09033927800   |             3600 | reserved | 2024-10-19 12:30:00+00 | 2024-10-09 11:42:37+00 | 2024-10-19 13:28:02+00 |             5385 |   2279104 |       3814 |          0
(4 rows)

Trying Django query same as:
start_date = datetime(2024, 10, 19, 0, 0, 0)
end_date = datetime(2024, 10, 19, 23, 59, 59)
dbug = Reservations.objects.all().filter(updated_at__range=(start_date, end_date))[:4]
data = list(dbug.values())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head(4))

Result is:
      id      idd  consultant_id_id  voip_number  client_id client_mobile  ...    status   reserve_timestamp          created_at created_by updated_by          updated_at
0  76407  2011050              5052         2217    1101151   09355648120  ...  reserved 2024-10-19 23:00:00 2024-10-14 12:10:03       3445          0 2024-10-19 23:58:01
1   1408  1958653              3791         1119     754939   09142477905  ...  reserved 2024-10-19 09:00:00 2024-09-28 09:47:04         87          0 2024-10-19 09:58:01
2   1514  1958759              5374         2571     947805   09334143576  ...  reserved 2024-10-19 13:00:00 2024-09-28 10:04:05       3802          0 2024-10-19 13:58:01
3  60371  1997347              5385         2589    1070143   09033927800  ...  reserved 2024-10-19 16:00:00 2024-10-09 15:12:37       3814          0 2024-10-19 16:58:02

[4 rows x 14 columns]

Shows that the encountered discrepancy within sql result between orm one.
The consultant_reservations table is appropriated the Reservation model.
Regards.

You set USE_TZ = False, so it will query with UTC time.

@willeM_VanOnsem
Yes, Right that. So because this Django project and it's database is manipulating with many developers and end-users, I can't changing deep changes.

Is USE_TZ = False only affect on time and not depending the date about?
Is it available remaining this USE_TZ as same and handling with start_date variable construction be appropriated the database settings?


@willeM_VanOnsem, How about that considering USE_TZ = False setting results Django will use the local time zone specified without converting to UTC? Why you said it results Django will query with UTC time?

you can use print(dbug.query) to check how Django filters.

SELECT ...,..., ..., "consultant_reservations"."voip_number", "consultant_reservations"."client_id", "consultant_reservations"."client_mobile", "consultant_reservations"."mobile_id", "consultant_reservations"."reserve_duration", "consultant_reservations"."status", "consultant_reservations"."reserve_timestamp", "consultant_reservations"."created_at", "consultant_reservations"."created_by", "consultant_reservations"."updated_by", "consultant_reservations"."updated_at" FROM "consultant_reservations" WHERE "consultant_reservations"."updated_at" BETWEEN 2024-10-19 00:00:00 AND 2024-10-19 23:59:59

The discrepancy is due to time zone conversions. The times in the SQL command issued through psql are interpreted based on the session's time zone. Try running SET TIME ZONE 'UTC' prior to the query. There is also a defect in the query: any updates that were performed after 2024-10-19 23:59:59 and before 2024-10-20 00:00:00 will be excluded.

Currently:
`SHOW TIME ZONE;
TimeZone
Etc/UTC
(1 row)`

The fundamental problem is caused by mixing time zone aware datetime objects in the DB with non timezone aware objects in Django. This results in implicit datetime time zone conversions. USE_TZ = TRUE configures Django to use time zone aware objects. Both Django and PostreSQL store times in UTC along with an offset when using time zone aware objects. The recommended approach is to use time zone aware objects in the code and only use local time at the user interface layer.

Please see Time Zones FAQ in the Django documentation and Don't Do This - Date/Time Storage in the PostgreSQL Wiki for additional information about working with datetime objects.
